# $.getJSON to $.ajax syntax?

Tags: ajax

I have this working `.getJSON`

```
$.getJSON('data3.json', function (data) {

})
```

If convert to `$.ajax` What should be the value for `data`?

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'data3.json',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: ?,
            success: function(data) {

            }
  });
```

Comment: You clearly are not passing any data to your $.getJSON function, so to get the same result, you don't need to pass any data to the $.ajax function either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should try this**

In the `ajax`, they are not compulsory to pass some parameters like `data`, `datatype` etc.
So you can call ajax without `data` parameter

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'data3.json',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

            }
  });
```